# Why is my javascript code not behaving as expected when run on console?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and I have the following description for the code below it.

I want to declare a variable called computerChoice and make it equal to Math.random();
    Print out computerChoice.

```
If computerChoice is between 0 and 0.33, make computerChoice equal to "rock".
If computerChoice is between 0.34 and 0.66, make computerChoice equal to "paper".
If computerChoice is between 0.67 and 1, make computerChoice equal to "scissors".
```

Here is my CODE.NB. When I run it on the console, it tells me there is a problem with my syntax!

```
var userChoice=prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice=Math.random();

{
   return console.log(computerChoice);
}
if(0<=computerChoice<=0.33)
{
  computerChoice="rock";

}
else if(computerChoice<=0.66)
{
   computerChoice="paper";

}
else
{
   computerChoice="scissors";

};
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. You get more help faster if people can easily read and understand your question.

Comment: if(0<=computerChoice<=0.33) is not valid.
Use : if(0<=computerChoice && computerChoice<=0.33)

Comment: Aside from the issue in the linked question, your code outputting computerChoice is *before* your code updating it. And you don't need `;` at the end of the block attached to an `if`, `else`, `while`, or other flow-control statement.